# How can I embed python in c ++ without exposing the my source code

Tags: python, c++, embedding

I would like to embedding python program from my c++ program. I looking for [Boost python](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/python/doc/html/tutorial/tutorial/embedding.html), [pypind](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/embedding.html), [C/Python API](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html)

But I has problems for this:

I don't want to exposing my python scripts on end-user computer, so my visualization is make python script to *.dll, *.exe, *.lib or something similar,
which can be called in C++ project
I refer to [Py2exe](https://pypi.org/project/py2exe/), but I don't know how can I get return result.

Thanks.

Comment: For a start, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. I'm also not quite sure what you expect, nor what you tried and what issues you encountered. As it stands, you seem to ask for an existing solution or someone to give you a guide how to achieve some badly-defined specs, which is a question that only attracts opinion.

Comment: Have a look at [Differences Between .pyc, .pyd, and .pyo Python Files](https://stackabuse.com/differences-between-pyc-pyd-and-pyo-python-files/). These are intermediate files which are not as easy to read as the source code but can be used by the Python interpreter as well. If you need something even more bullet-proof: Encrypt your Python source code and decrypt it at run-time after you have loaded it in your C++ appl. but before you pass it to the Python interpreter. (In our productive code, we went a bit further by tweaking the `import` of the Python interpreter for this.)

Comment: Thanks @Scheff.
I forgot to say, I'm not sure the end user has python installed before.
I'll do it like this: compile * .py files containing functions and classes into a * .pyd file, using them as part of the embedded system, with the script calling * .pyd compiled, I will encrypt them, decrypt it before pass to interpreter.

Comment: _I'm not sure the end user has python installed before._ If you embed Python scripts in your a C++ application you have to link the Python interpreter to it, don't you? So, it's regardless whether the user has a Python interpreter installed or not (at least, for your application).

Comment: Yes, At least, I can use the embedded distribution package, I'm trying not to ask users to install python themselves.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert python to exe with pyinstaller, and use a pipe to read standard out (print statements) and another pipe to send standard in (Console.WLine in C#, I dont know c++) so they can communicate